# How do I read properties in a nested object and return number if items that meet a condition?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, for-in-loop

I have the code below, which looks fine to me but keeps returning 0. I need to iterate through the named users in the user object and return the total number of users that have an online property value of true.

I've tried changing the newUser variable to an array and pushing the user into that array of online has a value of true, then returning the length of the array and it returns 0 as well.

```
    let users = {
      Alan: {
        age: 27,
        online: false
      },
      Jeff: {
        age: 32,
        online: true
      },
      Sarah: {
        age: 48,
        online: false
      },
      Ryan: {
        age: 19,
        online: true
      }
    };

    function countOnline(obj) {
      // change code below this line
      const newUser = 0;

      for (let user in obj) {
        if (user.online === true) {
        } else {
          newUser++;
        }
      }

      return newUser;
      // change code above this line
    }

    console.log(countOnline(users));
```

I'm expecting the for-in loop to iterate through the users in the user object and if there is a property of online with a value of true to increment the newUser varibale by 1 each time and then return the newUser variable with a value of 2. But it keeps returning 0.

Comment: `const newUser = 0;` <--- you can't change newUser if it is constant, use `let` instead

Comment: There's a much easier way to do this. Check my answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Array.reduce to reduce the array of users to a number

```js
const count = Object.keys(users).reduce((accum, username) => users[username].online ? accum + 1 : accum, 0)
```

or Array.filter to get the length of a filtered array of online users

```js
const count = Object.keys(users).filter(username => users[username].online).length;
```

o(n) solution without converting the object keys to an array

```js
let count = 0
for (const username in users) {
   count = users[username].online ? count + 1 : count
}
return count
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks! I used the last example. It seems I was trying to access the online property using dot notation alone, rather than placing the username variable in brackets. I'm still pretty new to JS, so not quite understanding things like this trip me up.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this alternately with [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter);

```js
let users = {
  Alan: {
    age: 27,
    online: false
  },
  Jeff: {
    age: 32,
    online: true
  },
  Sarah: {
    age: 48,
    online: false
  },
  Ryan: {
    age: 19,
    online: true
  }
};

let new_user_count = Object.keys(users).filter(x => users[x].online).length;
console.log(new_user_count);
```

Comment: Better use `Object.values()` if all your going to be doing is getting the values in `.filter()`

Answer (score 0):

you are iterating an object, and expect it to behave like an array with you for.

given the fact that you are iterating an object, you code should look like this:

```js
   let users = {
      Alan: {
        age: 27,
        online: false
      },
      Jeff: {
        age: 32,
        online: true
      },
      Sarah: {
        age: 48,
        online: false
      },
      Ryan: {
        age: 19,
        online: true
      }
    };

    function countOnline(obj) {
      // change code below this line
      let newUser = 0;

      for (let user of Object.values(obj)) {
        if (user.online === true) {
          newUser++;
        }
      }

      return newUser;
      // change code above this line
    }

    console.log(countOnline(users));
```

also keep in mind that you declared newUser as a const while you are changing it, so the correct way to do it is to declare it with let.

Comment: `let user in Object.keys(obj)` and `let user in obj` works the same. did you mean `Object.values`?

Comment: it still works wrong though. I'm editing the `for in` to `for of`. and change the if execution part

Comment: @sertsedat what is weird is that for me the code worked as before though. strange ...

Answer (score 0):

Use const instead of let. Mantain the function countUsersOnline
.

```
const users = {
  Alan: {
    age: 27,
    online: false
  },
  Jeff: {
    age: 32,
    online: true
  },
  Sarah: {
    age: 48,
    online: false
  },
  Ryan: {
    age: 19,
    online: true
  }
};

const countUsersOnline = (users) => Object.keys(users).filter(x => users[x].online).length;

console.log(countUsersOnline(users));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
countOnline(users)
{
   var a = 0;
   for(let user in users){ 
     if(users[user].online) 
       ++a; 
   }
   return a;
}
```

The function will check for each object within the object for online property if it is true then it will increment the count flag for online users